# MSSQL reading and splitting XML from varchar column

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I came across many solution but I am still stuck with this problem.

So, there is a column that contains XML like this one:

```
<Attributes>   <Map>     <entry key="DATA1" value="47317"/>     <entry key="DATA2" value="47316"/>     <entry key="DATA3" value="45972\47316\47317"/>  </Map> </Attributes>
```

I need to split that into three columns: DATA1, DATA2, DATA3. The problem is that sometimes DATA2 element simply doesnt exist, so I cannot use XQUERY like

```
SELECT CAST(attributes as xml).value('(/Attributes/Map/entry/@key)[1]', 'varchar(260)') as p FROM sometable
```

because if I use it to take the second element  then I could catch the DATA3 instead of DATA2.

The last goal is to make it in the way that can be use to make with CREATE VIEW statement. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT CAST(attributes as xml).value('(/Attributes/Map/entry[@key="DATA1"]/@value)[1]', 'varchar(260)') as DATA1
    , CAST(attributes as xml).value('(/Attributes/Map/entry[@key="DATA2"]/@value)[1]', 'varchar(260)') as DATA2
    , CAST(attributes as xml).value('(/Attributes/Map/entry[@key="DATA3"]/@value)[1]', 'varchar(260)') as DATA3
FROM sometable
```